# 301 Redirected requests not intercepted by Chrome WebRequest API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-status-code-301, chrome-webrequest

I developed a Chrome Extension which manipulates response headers of network requests.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  manipulateResponseHeaders,
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
  ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);

function manipulateResponseHeaders(details) {
  var modifiedHeaders = someModification(details.responseHeaders);
  return {responseHeaders: modifiedHeaders};
}
```

Consider website URL: `http://www.myntra.com`
This website redirects to `https://www.myntra.com` with status `301 Moved Permanently`.

My extension successfully intercepts `http://www.myntra.com` but not `https://www.myntra.com`.

Permissions in manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
  "contextMenus",
  "declarativeContent",
  "storage",
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "webNavigation",
  "tabs",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*"
]
```

Is it a restriction from Chrome WebRequest APIs or I'm missing some permissions?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Check https://crbug.com - maybe it's already reported or even fixed in Canary.

Comment: @wOxxOm Unfortunately, I don't find any existing bug.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm for suggesting that. I've submitted it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=922361. Also posted on Google groups: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/qCvqF1-omFE